# Why does changing form group in Javascript increase the spacing between input fields?

Tags: javascript, class, format

I have a last (I had asked previously) question about an application I am making. I have noticed that the spacing between input fields changes after I click the submit or reset buttons. Does this have to do with how classes are rendered? Is there any way to stop this kind of changing?

Also I am still in the process of cleaning up the code once it works so I do know it needs a bit of pruning.:)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Validation</title>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <style type="text/css">
         .container {
          width: 500px;
          clear:both;
         }
          .container input{
            width:100%;
            clear:both;
          }
          .buttons{
            text-align:center;
          }
    
          #output{
            text-align:center;
            visibility: hidden;
          }
    
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form id="myForm" onsubmit="return valfunc()";>
          <div class="container">
            <div id="usrnm">
              <label class="control-label">Username: </label>
              <input class="form-control" class="form-group" type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div id="pswrd">
              <label class="control-label">Password: </label>
              <input class="form-control" class="form-group" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div id="cnfrm">
              <label class="control-label">Confirm: </label>
              <input class="form-control" class="form-group" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm">
            </div>
            <div id="ag">
              <label class="control-label">Age: </label>
              <input class="form-control" class="form-group" type="text" name="age" id="age"> <br>
            </div>
          </div>
    
           <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="valfunc();">
            <input type="reset" id="resetbutton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="resetfunc()">
           </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div id="output">
          <ul> </ul>
        </div>
    
    
        <script>
     
    
        function valfunc() {
        
        document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "visible";
        var username = 
          document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = 
          document.getElementById("password").value;
        var confirm = 
          document.getElementById("confirm").value;
        var age =
          document.getElementById("age").value;
        var myerror = "";
        var nouser = 0;
    
        var error = [];
    
        if (username.length==0)
        {
          nouser = 1;
          myerror += "<li> Username field has been left blank.";
          error[0] = 1;
        }
    
        if (password.length==0)
        {
          myerror += "<li> Password field has been left blank.";
          error[1] = 1;
        }
    
        if (confirm.length==0)
        {
          myerror += "<li> Confirm field has been left blank.";
          error[2] = 1;
        }
    
        if (age.length==0)
        {
          myerror += "<li> Age field has been left blank.";
          error[3] = 1;
        }
    
        if ((username.length <5) || (username.length > 15))
        {
          myerror += 
          "<li> Username should be between 5 and 15 characters long.";
          error[0] = 1;
        }
        
        if (password !== confirm) {
          myerror += 
          "<li> Password and Confirm input text box values should match.";
          error[1] = 1;
          error[2] = 1 ; 
        }
    
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        if(username.match(letters)){
         }
         else if(nouser==1){
         }
         else {
          myerror += 
          "<li> Username can only have letters.";
          error[0] = 1;
         }
    
        var yesnum = 0;
        if(age.match(/^\d+$/)) {
          var yesnum = 1;
        }
    
        if ((age <= 0)||(yesnum==0)) {
          myerror += 
          "<li> Age should be a positive integer.";
          error[3] = 1;    
        } else {
          if ((age<18)||(age>110)){
          myerror += 
          "<li> Age should be between the values 18 and 110.";
          error[3] = 1;
          }
        }
        
    
        if (error[0]==1){
          document.getElementById("usrnm").className = "form-group has-error";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("usrnm").className = "form-group has-success";
        }
    
        if (error[1]==1){
          document.getElementById("pswrd").className = "form-group has-error";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("pswrd").className = "form-group has-success";
        }
    
        if (error[2]==1){
          document.getElementById("cnfrm").className = "form-group has-error";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("cnfrm").className = "form-group has-success";
        }
    
        if (error[3]==1){
          document.getElementById("ag").className = "form-group has-error";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("ag").className = "form-group has-success";
        }
    
    
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myerror;
        
        if (myerror.length > 1) {
          return false;
          document.getElementById("output").className = "alert alert-danger";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Form values successfully validated.";
          document.getElementById("output").className = "alert alert-success";
          return false;
        }
    
        }
    
        function resetfunc(){
          var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
          form.reset();
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "hidden";
    
          const output1 = document.getElementById("output");
          const username1 = document.getElementById("usrnm");
          const password1 = document.getElementById("pswrd");
          const confirm1 = document.getElementById("cnfrm");
          const age1 = document.getElementById("ag");
          username1.className = "form-group";
          password1.className = "form-group";
          confirm1.className = "form-group";
          age1.className = "form-group";
          output1.className = "alert"
        }
    
        </script>
    
    
    
    
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: peter: https://jsfiddle.net/dipakchavda2912/f90hsa17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.form-group {
   margin: 1rem;
}
```

You are adding .form-group class to the DIV (for ex id="usrnm") after the form is submitted. And the .form-group class has a bottom margin.

Update your

```
<div id="usrnm">
```

to

```
<div id="usrnm" **class="form-group"**>
```

This will fix the jump issue

Comment: I tried this but now it is doing the opposite. It starts with later margins and then tightens after form submittal

Comment: Actually the first part alone fixed the issues. I reverted to the original the part after you wrote "Also update" and now it works well! Thanks

Comment: Sorry I updated the code. The second statement actually overrides the existing classes and adds .has-error class.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are dynamically creating and inserting `<li>` elements into the page causing an incorrect HTML structure to be created. `<li>` elements must exist within either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element and those elements cause indentation. It is that indentation that you are seeing.

There is too much of your code that really needs to be rewritten, but below I have removed the `<li>`s from your error strings and you can see that the indentation of your buttons stops.

To correct this. Make sure that `<li>` element are properly placed into lists and that your list is separated from your buttons.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Validation</title>
    
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <style type="text/css">
         .container {
          width: 500px;
          clear:both;
         }
          .container input{
            width:100%;
            clear:both;
          }
          .buttons{
            text-align:center;
          }
    
          #output{
            text-align:center;
            visibility: hidden;
          }
    
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form id="myForm" onsubmit="return valfunc()";>
          <div class="container">
            <div id="usrnm">
              <label class="control-label">Username: </label>
              <input class="form-control" class="form-group" type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div id="pswrd">
              <label class="control-label">Password: </label>
              <input class="form-control" class="form-group" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div id="cnfrm">
              <label class="control-label">Confirm: </label>
              <input class="form-control" class="form-group" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm">
            </div>
            <div id="ag">
              <label class="control-label">Age: </label>
              <input class="form-control" class="form-group" type="text" name="age" id="age"> <br>
            </div>
          </div>
    
           <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="valfunc();">
            <input type="reset" id="resetbutton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="resetfunc()">
           </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div id="output">
          <ul> </ul>
        </div>
    
    
        <script>
     
    
        function valfunc() {
        
        document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "visible";
        var username = 
          document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = 
          document.getElementById("password").value;
        var confirm = 
          document.getElementById("confirm").value;
        var age =
          document.getElementById("age").value;
        var myerror = "";
        var nouser = 0;
    
        var error = [];
    
        if (username.length==0)
        {
          nouser = 1;
          myerror += "Username field has been left blank.";
          error[0] = 1;
        }
    
        if (password.length==0)
        {
          myerror += "Password field has been left blank.";
          error[1] = 1;
        }
    
        if (confirm.length==0)
        {
          myerror += "Confirm field has been left blank.";
          error[2] = 1;
        }
    
        if (age.length==0)
        {
          myerror += "Age field has been left blank.";
          error[3] = 1;
        }
    
        if ((username.length <5) || (username.length > 15))
        {
          myerror += 
          "Username should be between 5 and 15 characters long.";
          error[0] = 1;
        }
        
        if (password !== confirm) {
          myerror += 
          "Password and Confirm input text box values should match.";
          error[1] = 1;
          error[2] = 1 ; 
        }
    
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        if(username.match(letters)){
         }
         else if(nouser==1){
         }
         else {
          myerror += 
          "<li> Username can only have letters.";
          error[0] = 1;
         }
    
        var yesnum = 0;
        if(age.match(/^\d+$/)) {
          var yesnum = 1;
        }
    
        if ((age <= 0)||(yesnum==0)) {
          myerror += 
          "<li> Age should be a positive integer.";
          error[3] = 1;    
        } else {
          if ((age<18)||(age>110)){
          myerror += 
          "<li> Age should be between the values 18 and 110.";
          error[3] = 1;
          }
        }
        
    
        if (error[0]==1){
          document.getElementById("usrnm").className = "form-group has-error";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("usrnm").className = "form-group has-success";
        }
    
        if (error[1]==1){
          document.getElementById("pswrd").className = "form-group has-error";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("pswrd").className = "form-group has-success";
        }
    
        if (error[2]==1){
          document.getElementById("cnfrm").className = "form-group has-error";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("cnfrm").className = "form-group has-success";
        }
    
        if (error[3]==1){
          document.getElementById("ag").className = "form-group has-error";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("ag").className = "form-group has-success";
        }
    
    
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myerror;
        
        if (myerror.length > 1) {
          return false;
          document.getElementById("output").className = "alert alert-danger";
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Form values successfully validated.";
          document.getElementById("output").className = "alert alert-success";
          return false;
        }
    
        }
    
        function resetfunc(){
          var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
          form.reset();
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "hidden";
    
          const output1 = document.getElementById("output");
          const username1 = document.getElementById("usrnm");
          const password1 = document.getElementById("pswrd");
          const confirm1 = document.getElementById("cnfrm");
          const age1 = document.getElementById("ag");
          username1.className = "form-group";
          password1.className = "form-group";
          confirm1.className = "form-group";
          age1.className = "form-group";
          output1.className = "alert"
        }
    
        </script>
    
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
      </body>
    </html>
```